# How to call a action method from Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a action method that returns stringbuilder object which has a html table as output. i will this output to be fired from a tab click(having n number of tabs, on tab click name of tab is passed to a jquery function). please find below code

```
<li onclick="BindData1(this.id);" id="tab1">
            <a href="#tabs-2">Text</a></li>
```

code:

```
function BindData1(TechName) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "Controller")',
    data: {
      id: TechName
    }
  }).done(function() {
    if (data != undefined) {
      //bind to page
    } else
      alert('error');
  });
}
```

Comment: Use url:/controller/actionMethod

Comment: What is your problem and expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function BindData1(TechName) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ControllerName/ActionMethodName',
            data: { 'techname': "TechName" },
            success: function (data) {
              if(data.success)
                {
                   $("#contentwrapper").html(data);
                }
              else
                {
                   alert('error');
                }
}),
        });
    }
```